# Extends ValveBase class : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, tomcat-valve

I have created one web base application in java and i used the ValveBase class of java. The code is as below :

```
public class RenewSessionValve extends ValveBase {

    private String authenticationUrl = "j_security_check";

    @Override
    public void invoke(Request req, Response res) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("invoke in SessionFixationValve "+req.getRequestURI());
        if (req.getRequestURI().contains(authenticationUrl)) {

        // save old session
        Session oldSession = req.getSessionInternal(true);
        SavedRequest saved = (SavedRequest) oldSession.
        getNote(Constants.FORM_REQUEST_NOTE);
        System.out.println("before invalidating session");
        // invalidate old session
        req.getSession(true).invalidate();
        req.setRequestedSessionId(null);
        req.clearCookies();

        System.out.println("after invalidating session");
        // create a new session and set it to the request
        Session newSession = req.getSessionInternal(true);
        req.setRequestedSessionId(newSession.getId());

        System.out.println("saved obj is : "+saved);
        // copy data from the old session
        // to the new one
        if (saved != null) {
        newSession.setNote(Constants.FORM_REQUEST_NOTE, saved);
        }

        }
        System.out.println("before invoke");
        // after processing the request forward it
        getNext().invoke(req, res);
        }   
}
```

now i compiled the file and create a jar file of that project and put it into lib folder of server.
part of my server.xml file which i changed :

```
<Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="false" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true" xmlNamespaceAware="false" xmlValidation="false" deployOnStartup="false" deployXML="false">
        <Valve className="com.cmc.RenewSessionValve" />
</Host>
```

now i create one new project and run it. it gives me error like below :

```
SEVERE: Begin event threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cmc.RenewSessionValve
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:205)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Rule.begin(Rule.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1356)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1642)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:524)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:562)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Jun 23, 2014 10:33:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cmc.RenewSessionValve
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2832)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1359)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1642)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:524)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:562)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cmc.RenewSessionValve
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:205)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Rule.begin(Rule.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1356)
    ... 20 more
Jun 23, 2014 10:33:16 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester startElement
```

Comment: check your package name and folder structure should be same as package name

Comment: Yes, It is same as package name.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to you have placed your jar in incorrect server directory.

Answer (score -1):

For future reference - The custom valve source code must be exported into a jar file and placed inside `lib` folder of your tomcat directory. (not the same as your project directory)

Otherwise tomcat won't be able to find the custom class and will throw `ClassNotFoundException`